# Manipulating the Output of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular app that will serve as a social media dashboard. It will load and display content from Twitter, Instagram and Flickr based on search criteria.

I'm loading each resource and storing the results in an array called `$scope.items` and then in my view, I'm rendering them like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'galleryTimestamp':true">
    <p ng-if="item.galleryType=='instagram'">Instagram Photo</p>
    <p ng-if="item.galleryType=='twitter'">Twitter Post</p>
    <p ng-if="item.galleryType=='flickr'">Flickr Photo</p>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine, but I'd like to have a bit more control over how this renders. Ideally, I want to control the mix of content coming from each source. Right now, it will spit out five tweets in a row, then six instagram photos, then ten tweets, then a flickr photo.

Is there any way to either manipulate my `$scope.items` array or filter or sort these so that the page looks a bit more like [Instagram Photo] [Tweet] [Flickr Photo] and on... repeating over the set.

Comment: you can do whatever you want? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restructure your items property in your scope to loop through the way you want it, which is in this case [Instagram Photo][Tweet][Flickr Photo]. I would avoid using ng-if in this case and just restructure the items to be something like:

```
items = {
    instagram: 'instagram thing',
    tweet: 'tweet thing',
    flickr: 'flicker thing'
}
```